# Placing a stacklayout in the center of the screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I tried to insert the horizontaloptions="CenterAndExpand" code into all of the stacklayout path but didn't work.

It's still in the upper-left corner :( 
Somebody any idea? I actually don't use the grid, I just left it there.

My Code:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>

        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Source="BackgroundPicture.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
           <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegFirstNameEntry" Placeholder="Firstname" WidthRequest="177"></local:RoundedEntry>
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegLastNameEntry"  Placeholder="Lastname" WidthRequest="177"></local:RoundedEntry>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegPhoneNumberEntry" Placeholder="Phone" WidthRequest="177" Keyboard="Telephone"></local:RoundedEntry>
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegEmailEntry" Placeholder="Email" WidthRequest="177"></local:RoundedEntry>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegPasswordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" ></local:RoundedEntry>
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="RegPasswordAgainEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></local:RoundedEntry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: When you define CenterAndExpand in an empty layout, it will act like FillAndExpand, think of Expand like this: - it starts in the "center", and it "expands" to the available space -, this means that if the available space is from top to bottom, it will fill all of the space, try putting your grid to Center only, and the inner stack to center too

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `StackLayout` defaults are `FillAndExpand`.

To center it inside `Grid` set `StackLayout`'s `HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"`.